# Деобфускация приложения "ProGuard". Чтобы расшифровывать трассировки стека для этой версии APK, загрузите файл деобфускации приложения "ProGuard"

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console

**Google Play Console** сообщила:

**Деобфускация приложения "ProGuard"**

> Чтобы расшифровывать трассировки стека для этой версии APK, загрузите
>   файл деобфускации приложения "ProGuard".

Где его взять?

Это же сообщение на английском:

**ProGuard deobfuscation**

> Upload your ProGuard deobfuscation file in order to deobfuscate future
>   stack traces for this APK version.

Comment: Вот официальный ответ на английском от Google поддержки: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6295281?hl=en Но не понятно что же делать? Какой файл деобфускации она просит? ) Где он находится в проекте? Или как-то формируется?

Comment: Вот ответ на английском SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39094943/android-what-is-proguard-and-proguard-mapping Но что делать абсолютно не понятно! )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оказалось...

Премудрый **Файл деобфускации** называется вот таким простым именем **mapping.txt**, что в переводе на русский переводится примерно как **Файл соответствия**

В исходном проекте (на компьютере) этот файл находится здесь:

> \app\build\outputs\mapping\release\mapping.txt

Его и нужно грузить в Google Play Console, тогда места ошибок будут четко привязаны к строкам Вашего исходного ("засекреченного" деобфускацией) кода.

После того, когда отпадет необходимость поиска ошибок в исходном коде, **файл деобфускации следует удалить** из Google  Play Console, чтобы опять все концы в воду... :)

Comment: У меня уже каталога mapping нет. Android Studio 3 5 2

Comment: @Freqnsy Вы нашли решение? У меня в проекте нет файла mapping.txt)))

Comment: Видимо, все уже изменилось... Sorry, я сейчас не в курсе, что и как изменилось...